# Searching for prior art: what cites this?

Tags: prior-art

I have found a patent on Google Patents which, while not infringing on what I want to patent, could form prior art to something that does infringe on what I want to patent.  I am finding it hard to start at this one patent and go forward to see which patents cite this as prior art.  Does anyone know a nice way to do this?  Anything I find would form very important prior art for my patent and may even preclude my patent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google patents is a great way to track this. On the overview view there are hyperlinks to all the US patent documents that the patent cites and below that are hyperlinks to everything that cited the patent in question. It could fan out to be a large number of things to plow through but following citations forward and backward is an important aspect of a search.